# Using GraphQL context variable in React component GraphQL query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to construct a GraphQL query within my React component, I need to limit the amount of results returned. I'm setting the limit value within the "context" property of the "createPage" function in the gatsby-node.js file.

In my React component, I can see that the limit property is being passed in via "props.pageContext.limit". I need to take this limit value and pass it to the GraphQL query at the bottom of my React component

Below is what I've tried but it doesn't work, if I omit the limit value from the query then it returns all results.

```
//gatsby-node.js
...    
    const postsPerPage = 3;
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: path.resolve("./src/templates/page.js"),
      context: { 
                 limit: postsPerPage,
                 slug: node.fields.slug,
                 category: node.frontmatter.category
               }  
      });
...


//my-component.js
...
    export const query = graphql`
        query($limit: Int!, $slug: String!) {
          markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
            html
            frontmatter {
              category
            }
          }
          allMarkdownRemark(limit: $limit) {
            edges {
              node {
                frontmatter {
                  title
                  excerpt
                }
                fields {
                    slug
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `
```

Comment: And the GraphQL query is in the file `/src/templates/page.js` ?

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL queries are automatically executed with the specified parameters only when they are exported from page template components. In your case, if this query was present in `./src/templates/page.js`, the query would be executed. You could then pass the data to child components through props.

Your query is currently getting ignored because Gatsby does not automatically execute queries in non-page components. You can use the `StaticQuery` component or the `useStaticQuery` hook to query data from child components. However, as the names suggest, these are static queries and do not accept any parameters.

If you really wish to describe the query in the child components, you can also look into `Fragments` which is a way for you to divide large queries into multiple reusable parts.

Useful links:

[useStaticQuery hook](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/use-static-query/)

[StaticQuery component](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/)

[Query Fragments](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/querying-with-graphql/#fragments)